# How to reload fragment in ViewPager each time the page is selected?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using `mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener` to detect when a user navigated to a specific page. Each time he navigates to this specific page, I have to reload the `Fragment` or return it to its original state.

I tried using `replace` but the app breaks on the first parameter which is the `ViewPager` itself.

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewPager, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I tried to use the `adapter` itself, but I was brought to a dead end.

Where am I making a mistake? How can I reload the fragment each time a user navigate to a specific page?

Comment: try fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment); fragmentTransaction.attach(fragment);

Comment: You could implement a reload/reset method on each fragment and invoke that method each time a new page is selected.

Comment: fail incorrect design principle.  You end up with an app that stutters when the user flips pages.  The correct design pattern is to refresh off screen pages when they are off screen.

Comment: @danny117 I can do that as well. I did not think of performance right now but how to override the crash. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I managed to finalize this via public method within the fragment which resets the values to default ones. But I am still waiting for a "beter" way, This one seems hack-like.